# Determine color to input values?

Tags: excel, vba

[image]
Is there any way to determine the color of the cell to include a value on the next column?
Can't figure out how to go about it.

Tried using VBA to find color of excel

> ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(217, 225, 242)
> ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 225, 255)

Lost on what to do after getting the color

Comment: What about using conditional formatting? You can read about it [here](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/conditional-formatting/)

Comment: `Sub test()
Debug.Print ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex
End Sub` look at what number is in the `Immediate Window` then you can use that in an if statement to add value to the next column

Comment: Are the cells colored manually or using Conditional Formatting?   If CF then you need to read `DisplayFormat.Interior.Color`

Comment: Conditional Formatting. For the cells color